# Python Subprocess The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to download an audio dataset, I have all the audio's link stored in a csv. I read the csv and get all the links now I have to download the audio's one by one. Here's the code.

```
if not os.path.exists(audio_path_orig):
    line = f"wget {episode_url}"
    print('command:',line)
    process = subprocess.Popen([(line)],shell=True)
    process.wait()
```

for a sample, the line variable contains

```
wget https://stutterrockstar.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/male-episode-14-with-grant.mp3
```

Note that the url works and you can check for yourself, but when I try to download it using python it gives me the below error.

`error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Comment: Could you please provide more information from the error message, your code in the section you posted seems to be fine.

Comment: I'm getting the error 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `Popen`:

> *args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string or path-like object. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence.

And:

> Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass *args* as a sequence.

Also:

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the `run()` function for all use cases it can handle.

So use:

```
if not os.path.exists(audio_path_orig):
    args = ["wget", f"{episode_url}"]
    print('command:', " ".join(args))
    result = subprocess.run(
        args, capture_output=True, text=True
    )
    if result.returncode != 0:
        print(f"wget returned error {result.returncode}")
        print("Standard output:")
        print(result.stdout)
        print("Error output:")
        print(result.stderr)
```